# How do I make Charts always show gridlines?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I'm using Charts 3.1.1 and I can't figure out how to make the chart always display x-Axis gridlines:

[image]

In this example, I want the chart to display the xAxis gridlines and labels after Apr 25, which would be Apr 26, Apr 27, Apr 28, Apr 29, Apr 30, May 1.

I created this class to generate enough dates to fill in the blanks when there isn't a datapoint for each subsequent day that I want to show:

```
class AxisValuesGenerator: NSObject {
    var days: [String]? = []

    func generatexAxisDates(liftEvents: [LiftEvent]) -> [String]? {
        var dates: [Date] = []
        let intervalBetweenDates: TimeInterval = 3600 * 24 // 3600 = 1 hour
        let firstDate = (liftEvents.first?.date)! // - intervalBetweenDates
        var lastDate = liftEvents.last?.date

        if Double(liftEvents.count) < 7 {
            let daysToAdd = intervalBetweenDates * Double(7 - liftEvents.count)
            lastDate = lastDate?.addingTimeInterval(daysToAdd)
            for _ in 0...6 {
                dates = self.intervalDates(from: firstDate, to: lastDate!, with: intervalBetweenDates)
            }
        } else {
            dates = self.intervalDates(from: firstDate, to: lastDate!, with: intervalBetweenDates)
        }

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"

        days = dates.map {dateFormatter.string(from: $0)}

        return days

    }

func intervalDates(from startDate: Date, to endDate:Date, with interval:TimeInterval) -> [Date] {
    guard interval > 0 else { return [] }

    var dates:[Date] = [startDate]
    var currentDate = startDate

    while currentDate <= endDate {
        currentDate = currentDate.addingTimeInterval(interval)
        dates.append(currentDate)
    }

    return dates
}
```

and it does generate the dates I want:

```
▿ Optional<Array<String>>   ▿ some : 7 elements
   - 0 : "Apr 25"
   - 1 : "Apr 26"
   - 2 : "Apr 27"
   - 3 : "Apr 28"
   - 4 : "Apr 29"
   - 5 : "Apr 30"
   - 6 : "May 1"
   - 7 : "May 2"
```

but the chart doesn't display them.

How can I get the chart to display the missing gridlines?

UPDATE:

I've tried setting `setVisibleXRange` and `setLabelCount` (forced) like this:

```
chartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 2.0, maxXRange: 6.0)

let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(7, force: true)
```

and the chart renders properly if I have 6 or more values to plot. But you can see that with only 2 values I'm able to force the lines but the xAxis labels are wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data setup and chart view setup are two different things. Charts give you lots of controls to customise HOW your data is displayed.

Try something like this on your chart view:

```
chartView.xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
chartView.xAxis.labelCount = 7
```

To show x labels where there is no y value, I used "empty" y value (it was 0 in my case, but could be something else in yours). To ensure you can see correct Y range, use left/right axis param

```
chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 5
```

Here is what it looks like for me:
[image]

Comment: True, they are different things, but as far as I can tell there are dependencies between the two via the x and y axis. My data has dates that are used to create the xAxis labels. That dependency is where my problem is. If I don't have enough data points to fill up the view port (let's say that's 7 values), how do I tell the chart to still draw 6 more labels and gridlines for which there is no data, and therefore no date?

Comment: How about adding fake data? You can set minY/maxY values, so if data point is outside that range it won't be visible, but will force xValue to appear. Not the most elegant solution but I'd try something like that

Comment: I realized that's exactly what I did in one of my charts. I've updated response, hope it's more helpful now

Comment: Thanks, Halyna. That looks similar to what I'm trying to achieve. I will experiment with your suggestion and let you know what happens.

Comment: @halynarabashko - I'm setting the minY/maxY values based on the data because I want all values to be plotted and with scaling and pinch/zoom enabled I don't think faking the data will work. If I'm misunderstanding your suggestion please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @HalynaRubashko did you find a solution? I have the same issue: display grid lines and x labels when there is no y value